# Filtering on Managed Metadata - MS Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, flow

So apparently managed metadata fields are not supported with ODATA Filter Queries in MS Flow. We need a workaround so we can filter the results from a 'Get items' action. Does anyone know a clever way (besides copying the metadata to a text field) to filter on managed metadata using Flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list named Test that contains a managed metadata field named Department, you can get all of the items where the value of the Department field is Accounting using the following SharePoint REST API POST request:

```
_api/Web/lists/getByTitle('Test')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1={"ViewXml":"<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Department'/><Value Type='TaxonomyFieldType'>Accounting</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"}
```

In Flow you would use the Send an HTTP request to SharePoint to make that REST API call.

[image: SharePoint REST API call in Flow]

You could then use a Select action to extract the values you need from the response. In the example below I'm selecting the value of the Title field.

[image: Using the Select action to extract the Title field values]

The value of the From expression is: `body('Send_an_HTTP_request_to_SharePoint')['d']['results']`

The value of the Title expression is: `item()['Title']`

Comment: didn't know you could put a View query in REST. I swapped the 'Select' function with 'Create CSV' and it worked great!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for this issue is adding a Condition. Then use the dynamic content of Managed metadata label to check if it equal to the specific value.

More information check the similar post:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Filtering-taxonomy/td-p/278941